# Why getline function in my C++ program is not working as expected

Tags: c++, getline

My c++ program is mentioned below.

```
int choice;
while(choice!=2){
    cin>>choice;
}
string name;
string pass;
cout<<"Username: ";
getline(cin, name);
cout<<"Password: ";
getline(cin, pass);
```

I want my program to work like until I enter 2, it keeps on asking me input number. And when I enter 2 it prompts me for username and password. Starting program is working fine but the problem is that I have used getline function to take string input but it is asking separate input for username and password. It is only asking input in one line like USERNAME: PASWORD:
**OUTPUT:**

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: `while(choice!=2)` is undefined behavior as `choice` is uninitialized. Also see [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: When you type `2<enter>`, `cin>>choice;` reads the `2`, leaving the `<enter>` in the buffer and `getline(cin, name);` will read this.

Comment: Offtopic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question